# Laravel 4 + Iron: 'Http_Exception' with message 'http error: 404 | {"msg":"Not found"}'

Tags: php, laravel-4, iron.io

I'm trying to register a subscriber using the command `php artisan queue:subscribe queue-name url` .

Works perfectly on my local server using NGROK but throws a `Http_Exception` with message `http error: 404 | {"msg":"Not found"}` upon deploying to the remote server, I can't register a subscriber on my remote server.

Even if I do it manually through iron.io dashboard, still throws the same error.

Below is part of my stack trace;

```
[2015-02-20 12:30:01] production.ERROR: exception 'Http_Exception' with 
message 'http error: 404 | {"msg":"Not found"}' in 
/srv/users/serverpilot/../public/vendor/iron- 
io/iron_core/IronCore.class.php:353
Stack trace:

/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/../public/vendor/iron-io/iron_core/IronCore.class.php(344): 
IronCore->reportHttpError(404, '{"msg":"Not fou...')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

99.9% it's wrong `iron_mq` version. Please try to set version `1.*`

```
"iron_mq":"1.*"
```

Comment: I think this is what I was missing, [branches](https://github.com/iron-io/iron_mq_php). The information under Branches title. Thanks @thousandsofthem worked like a charm.

Comment: Man I thought I was going crazy until I found this and it cleared everything up. Thanks.